# Unexpected behaviour with long keys using bcrypt

Tags: scala, security, bcrypt

I was testing my authorization implementation. I'm using bcrypt for some login information. While testing I shortened the key (just to try out a different key) and to my suprise, it validated as a working key. This doesn't seem to be the case with shorter keys (like "hello" and "hell").

I was wondering if this is an expected behaviour or if this is a bug with the library. I suspect that this isn't the expected behaviour. The library I'm using is [this one](https://github.com/t3hnar/scala-bcrypt), and here is [this same question as an issue](https://github.com/t3hnar/scala-bcrypt/issues/23).

```scala
"Shorter key" should "not work with bcrypt" in {
    val key = "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"
    val shorterKey = "b5c805cf4f1ccd534ad36c4480c835c57caf487dec1953568d486e0af70147f1872b2592c2491dde0eb7ebf8efd27bd3bd9db3dc2e33c0ac94144a1a40bac65a95fcf5ae2b3298c478da86346b6f1e1a57cba70a97ade3d3df821faf646f2d4cb4506bd98d1239b215bb590edbed7c8b6a957a1898889e5d49d53546f71100cf0a2a0880f9625a8d17e2efe0d45c99d9906a6a06a5baee710918e37361574e56bff5ded7fc98c73f20b0cf9e42e59106683e9e60f372b4263ba2ae3dce1f19fb5ba17141f01575c4d7eb7754485fb7eb0353c47a48ca0cc53ce725ff15cf96caa86bf0680edb4414cfc1e4f5c86a8d03d1436abbc72e0c0bc7c33866c19b778520974f279b0c6b1a0f6d5e5544581cc0d85a514b1f4953668c854ec644bf29c7cc669f95ffcba3bdc12382bbaa6df3c3667d1e119c26f502f30b5538003971b8c69cdb175ab41406dcd73977d2290706c4c2bd0eedebcab3c7ba4e0a8f1fb1752963ff375d2598c14a2c412ecfd5e51d9a52625adb67c97117cbb28caca75b70eec1e549fee56d80a92216b2c371206e9e8055419577b0e2fed123fe293e70bce784d111e668b86b51d526462ada227b2216092ecd19002ecfd1a4a7ad7bd2be6009c3ab7e58dedf19d06238619524e7b8fc49"
    val evenShorterKey = "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"
    val bcryptedKey = "$2a$12$gF8jgmfUpYPvjX0FsVadhugiwuiEpt1.jdOg3GCQB1aqFGdt1Kr5G"
    key.isBcryptedSafe(bcryptedKey) should be(Success(true))
    shorterKey.isBcryptedSafe(bcryptedKey) should be(Success(false))
    evenShorterKey.isBcryptedSafe(bcryptedKey) should be(Success(false))
  }
```

Looking forward for your answer. For now I'll be adding a hashing step in between and hoping that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like bcrypt has a maximal password length. Please have a look at this: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39849/does-bcrypt-have-a-maximum-password-length. Does not seem to be a scala issue only.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Considering these keys are already distributed, do you think it would a good idea to hash the incoming keys to convert them to fixed length, and then bcrypt them?

Comment: I would leave it as is and not put additional efforts into cropping the keys. This is how bcrypt works. :)